# Почему не выполняется скрипт для динамически открытого окна?

Tags: javascript

Задача: на странице `http://domenA.ru` в неком файле html имеется скрипт следующего вида:

```
var subWindow = window.open("http://domenB.ru","ind"); 
var s2=subWindow.document.createElement('script'); 
s2.src="http://domenA.ru/test.js"; 
subWindow.document.body.appendChild(s2);
```

Причём скрипт работает, если вместо `http://domenB.ru` использовать `http://domenA.ru`, то есть если они в одном домене, даже если это localhost. Но не работает, если домены разные. Причём вообще не достучаться до другой страницы в этом случае, не работает даже

```
subWindow.document.title = "Temp Title";
```

А вот `subWindow.close();` работает...

В чём может быть причина и вообще, возможно заставить скрипт так работать? 
Я с JS знаком весьма поверхностно.

Comment: Это "Same origin policy"

Answer (score 1):

В web есть такая политика, которая запрещает исполнять скрипты с другого сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Защита. Мало ли, Ваш скрипт будет куки стягивать с того сайта!

Хочу добавить: во фрейм тоже не получится с помощью сценария проникнуть, если фрейм на другом домене.

**P.S.** [ХэшКод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), понял с абзацами. НО тег 
 в диве previewer отобразился как перенос строки. Вам стоит исправить =)